# T_BOOLEAN_AND error?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, syntax-error

whats wrong with this? anybody help me please..

```
if(stripos($nerde, $hf) !== false) && (stripos($nerde, $rs) !== false){
    @mysql_query("update table set dltur = '3' where id = '".$ppl[id]."'");

}
else {
//dont do anything
}
```

i get T_BOOLEAN_AND error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire condition needs parentheses:

```
if((stripos($nerde, $hf) !== false) && (stripos($nerde, $rs) !== false)){
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole expression of an [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) condition needs to be put in parentheses. But you’re already closing that part of the `if` statement after the first `false`:

```
if(stripos($nerde, $hf) !== false) && (stripos($nerde, $rs) !== false){
  ^       ^___________^          ^
  |______________________________|
```

Write it this way:

```
if (stripos($nerde, $hf) !== false && stripos($nerde, $rs) !== false)
```

Or you put parentheses around the whole expression (Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested):

```
if ((stripos($nerde, $hf) !== false) && (stripos($nerde, $rs) !== false))
```