# fwrite, syntax error unexpeted T_BOOLEAN_AND

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am writing to a .csv file, inside my php I have the following line which results in the error above:

```
if ($playerH1 == "Choose Player") && strlen($highlightsplayerH1) > 0){} else {fwrite($fs,$playerH1." - ".$ph1."\n");}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641595/t-boolean-and-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `(` at the beginning of your if statement

Comment: woohoo - that worked, guess when you are up till 4am adding and removing parenthesis, you get a little parenthesis blind!